# Agregar meses a una fecha en un input con javascript

Tags: javascript

encontré un JS que aumenta la los meses a una fecha pero solo funciona cuando el mes es enero (01), o sea, si pongo 10/01/2019 y le agrego 9 meses ejecuta: 10/10/2019.

Pero si pongo 10/05/2019 ejecuta: 10/02/2053.

Alguien puede ayudarme con este JS. Gracias!

```js
function Add12(hi){
 var obj=document.getElementById('MyDate');
 var obj2=document.getElementById('MyDate2');
 var val=obj.value;
 var date=new Date(val.split('/')[2],(val.split('/')[1]-1+(hi[1]?hi:"0"+hi[0])),val.split('/')[0]);
 obj2.value=Format(date.getDate())+'/'+Format((date.getMonth()+1))+'/'+date.getFullYear();
}
function Format(nu){
 if (nu<10){ nu='0'+nu; }
 return nu;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Usen 10/01/2019: Funciona!</li>
<li>Usen 10/08/2019: Sale mal!</li>
</ul>
<input id="MyDate" value="" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA">

<h5>Agregar meses:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="" onclick="Add12(this.children[0].getAttribute('value'));"><input type="radio" name="mes" value="9">9 meses</label>
    <label for="" onclick="Add12(this.children[0].getAttribute('value'));"><input type="radio" name="mes" value="10">10 meses</label>
    <label for="" onclick="Add12(this.children[0].getAttribute('value'));"><input type="radio" name="mes" value="12">12 meses</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="holi"></div>
<input id="MyDate2" value="" placeholder="Fecha final" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en el parámetro del mes para construir la fecha `new Date(año,mes,día)` ya que los datos son cadenas tanto el parámetro de la función `hi` como los `split` que realiza a la fecha del `input` y al sumar dan un cadena con valor interno numérico mayor.

*Demo del resultado de su Ejemplo*

```js
var val = '10/05/2019'; 
var hi = '9';
var mes = (val.split('/')[1]-1+(hi[1]?hi:"0"+hi[0]));
console.log(mes);
```

Este valor *409* es lo que realmente se le pasa al constructor y si le restamos los `7` meses que hacen falta para llegar al `2020` quedaría `402`y si este valor lo dividimos entre `12` meses por año , no da `33` , entonces si sumamos estos valores  no dará `2053` *(2020+33)* que es el resultado de final que arroja su función.

Para mejorar esta función sería mejor si se convierte a entero los valores con `parseInt()` además realizar una sola vez el `split` al valor de la fecha ingresada *(Posible resultado final)*

```js
function Add12(hi){
 var obj=document.getElementById('MyDate');
 var obj2=document.getElementById('MyDate2');
 var val=obj.value.split('/');
 var date=new Date(
   val[2],
   (parseInt(val[1]-1)+parseInt((hi[1]?hi:0+hi[0]))),
   val[0]
  );
 obj2.value = date.toLocaleDateString();
}
```

```html
<input id="MyDate" value="" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA">

<h5>Agregar meses:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="" onclick="Add12(this.children[0].getAttribute('value'));"><input type="radio" name="mes" value="9">9 meses</label>
    <label for="" onclick="Add12(this.children[0].getAttribute('value'));"><input type="radio" name="mes" value="10">10 meses</label>
    <label for="" onclick="Add12(this.children[0].getAttribute('value'));"><input type="radio" name="mes" value="24">12 meses</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="holi"></div>
<input id="MyDate2" value="" placeholder="Fecha final" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar con cualquier **Date()** solo es necesario trabajar con las propiedades de **getMonth() y setMonth()** de las fechas. Estos métodos retornan valores numéricos, que son necesarios para realizar la operación,

```js
var obj=document.getElementById('MyDate');
var obj2 = document.getElementById('MyDate2');
var obj3 = document.getElementById('MyDate3');
obj.value = setFormato(new Date());

function AddMes(){
 var fecha = new Date(obj.value);
 fecha.setMonth( fecha.getMonth() + +(obj2.value));
 obj3.value = setFormato(fecha);
}

function setFormato(fecha){
    var day = ("0" + fecha.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (fecha.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var date = (month)+"-"+(day)+"-"+fecha.getFullYear();
    return date;
}
```

```html
<input id="MyDate" value="">
<input id="MyDate2" value="" placeholder="Sumar meses" onChange="AddMes()">
<input id="MyDate3" value="" placeholder="Resultado final" disabled>
```